# Cache parts of block

Tags: cache, block-cache

I have a block which basically serves 3 sections of a page. I want to cache the respective block but one of the section doesn't need to be cached.
I am new to Magento and even newer to the caching part of it.
I've overwrote the getCacheKey() and getCacheTags()to have some custom functionality.
Is there a way to partially cache a block?

Answer (score 1):

Use below snippet in your block file to cache content.

```
$cacheId = "your_custom_cache_unique_name";
$html    = Mage::app()->loadCache($cacheId);
if (!$html) {
   $html = $this->renderView(); // Set appropriate data here..
   Mage::app()->saveCache($html, $cacheId);
}
return $html;
```

If you are having multi-store website, you can use

```
$cacheId = "your_custom_cache_unique_name_".Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
```